# How to enable real-time linting while typing with rust-analyzer in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, rust, rust-analyzer

I have rust-analyzer extension in VSCode.

In settings I only changed `Rust-analyzer › Check On Save: Command` from `check` to `clippy` (this shouldn't matter).

Problem is I don't see errors when I type, only after I save.

Typed (no error):

[image: typing]

Saved (can see error):

[image: saved]

Can it be changed?

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with `"rust-analyzer.checkOnSave.command"`, or am I missing something? Aren't you simply asking, if it's possible to have rust-analyzer continuously run, as you type?

Comment: @vallentin yep, i just sad all my settings if it maybe break something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Problem is I don't see errors when I type, only after I save.

Rust-analyzer does not support real-time linting (yet?).

In short, rust-analyzer essentially runs `cargo check`. For small projects this can be quite fast. However, as project sizes increase, this can take significantly more time, which makes it unfeasible to check in real-time.

See also [issue #4185](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer/issues/4185) and ["Drawbacks"](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/blog/2020/04/20/first-release.html#drawbacks) on the ["First Release" post](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/blog/2020/04/20/first-release.html).

---

The next best thing you can do (as you already know), is to use "check on save":

```json
"rust-analyzer.checkOnSave.enable": true
```

*(which is enabled by default in the VSCode extension)*

Answer (score 3):

You could:

- Enable autoSave in your settings.json file within the .vscode folder.

  ```
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "files.autoSaveDelay": 20,
  ```
- Install Error Lens extension for vscode:

  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens

This way you'll get inline errors while writing rust code.